# ¿Cómo hacer web scraping con PHP?

Tags: php

¡Buenas a todos!

Tengo que hacer un ***web scraping*** a la siguiente pagina web:
http://stats.betradar.com/s4/?clientid=1739&language=en#2_1,3_1,22_1,5_40942,9_headtohead,7_33,178_31

El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:

```
<?php


    function curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init($url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
        $info = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);
        return $info; 
    }

    $sitioweb = curl("http://stats.betradar.com/s4/?clientid=1739&language=en#2_1,3_1,22_1,5_40942,9_headtohead,7_33,178_31");  
    echo $sitioweb;
?>
```

¿Alguien me podria ayudar?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Imanol, ¿y el código?, se te olvidó ponerlo :D

Comment: <?php

    
    function curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init($url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
        $info = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);
        return $info; 
    }

    $sitioweb = curl("http://stats.betradar.com/s4/?clientid=1739&language=en#2_1,3_1,22_1,5_40942,9_headtohead,7_33,178_31");  
    echo $sitioweb;
?>

Comment: hola @jonilgz ahora te sale el codigo? un saludo :)

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con ***web scraping***? ¿Podrías explicarlo?

Comment: Hola @Orici tengo que sacar los datos de esa pagina web, guardarlas y luego que se actualizen automaticamente

Comment: Y cuán es la dificultad que estás teniendo? `$sitioweb` contiene el texto de la página?

Comment: @amenadiel con el codigo que he puesto no me aparece ningun dato ya que la pagina web utiliza JavaScript para proteger los datos

Comment: No es para proteger los datos ;) sólo se llena dinámicamente y cuando tu CURL se trae el contenido sólo obtiene el esqueleto.

Comment: @amenadiel mi correo electronico es el siguiente:garmendiaimanol69@gmail.com enviame un correo y hablamos de hay que no entiendo unas cosas :)

Comment: No se acostumbra ofrecer ese nivel de ayuda personalizada en StackOverflow. Sino imagínate cómo tendría mi casilla de correos, llena de preguntas

Comment: @amenadiel ¿Y podria contactar contigo de alguna manera?

Comment: Te hice un repo en github para que juegues. Puedes usar las issues del mismo repo para preguntar, si quieres: https://github.com/HuasoFoundries/puppeteer-example/issues

Answer (score 4):

La página que intentas scrapear parte como un contenedor vacío que luego se llena a través de sucesivas llamadas ajax, las cuales no traen los valores en sí sino una estructura custom que a su vez alimenta una librería local y ésta hace el parsing. PHP no es la herramienta indicada para parsear ese tipo de páginas.

Mi sugerencia sería **usar un browser headless** para hacer este trabajo, uno capaz de abrir la página y esperar a que un cierto selector esté presente en la página, para recién entonces devolver el contenido. Yo sé que te debes sentir más a gusto usando PHP puro pero dudo que se pueda hacer directamente. En esta respuesta, aunque me voten negativo hasta el infinito, te muestro una solución usando **Node.js**

Te hice un repo de ejemplo en [HuasoFoundries/puppeteer-example](https://github.com/HuasoFoundries/puppeteer-example). Si quieres probarlo tienes que tener `git`, `node` y `npm` en tu máquina para que esto funcione:

```
git clone https://github.com/HuasoFoundries/puppeteer-example.git
cd puppeteer-example
npm install
node betradar.js
```

Eso te va a tirar a la consola el contenido de la página tal como es una vez que se han llenado los contenedores con las llamadas ajax que ocurren en ella.

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo por debajo? Primero, instalo [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), la herramienta oficial del equipo detrás de Google Chrome para manejar un browser headless por línea de comando. Segundo, lo utilizo con el siguiente código:

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    betradar = 'http://stats.betradar.com/s4/?clientid=1739&language=en#2_1,3_1,22_1,5_40942,9_headtohead,7_33,178_31';

puppeteer.launch()
    .then(function (browser) {
        return browser.newPage()
            .then(function (page) {
                return page.goto(betradar)
                    .then(function () {
                        return page.waitFor('.percentagebar');
                    }).then(function () {
                        return page.content();
                    }).then(function (contents) {

                        return fs.writeFile('betradar.html', contents, function (err, results) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error(err);
                            }
                            console.log(contents);
                        });
                    });
            }).then(function () {
                return browser.close();
            });
    });
```

En el cual abro la página, espero a que exista un elemento con la clase `percentagebar` (puede ser otro selector, sólo elegí ese al ojo), y cuando ese selector está presente, asumo que la página ha cargado y **copio sus contenidos, que quedan guardados en el archivo** `betradar.html`. Ese archivo podrías usarlo tú desde PHP para parsearlo como querías hacer en tu llamada remota.

---

Comentario al márgen:

Hay una manera más elegante de escribir lo mismo que está en [betradar_async.js](https://github.com/HuasoFoundries/puppeteer-example/blob/master/betradar_async.js):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'),
    betradar = 'http://stats.betradar.com/s4/?clientid=1739&language=en#2_1,3_1,22_1,5_40942,9_headtohead,7_33,178_31';

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(betradar);
    await page.waitFor('.percentagebar');
    const contents = await page.content();
    console.log(contents);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Pero para usarla necesitarías una versión de Node superior a la 7.6 así que preferí dejarte el ejemplo más tradicional.

Comment: querria que los datos se guardasen en una base de datos y que se actualicasen automaticamente. ¿podria ser posible? @amenadiel

Comment: Mi respuesta sólo te deja en el mismo punto donde terminaba tu pregunta, sólo que ahora en vez de una URL que viene vacía, tienes un archivo html lleno con la información que quieres parsear y que puedes abrir con `file_get_contents`. El parseo de ese HTML para extraer los elementos que te interesan depende de qué datos de interesan y en qué contenedores están, lo cual es una pregunta distinta

Answer (score 0):

Por el código que pones, intentas leer el contenido de una URL y luego imprimir su contenido (supongo que sólo para ver que lo tienes). Es relativamente más sencillo, puedes abrir una URL como si fuera un fichero con la función nativa:

```
string file_get_contents( $resource_path )
```

Y esta es la parte fácil, porque si la URL esta disponible, no suele haber problemas.

Yo tengo una función para esto:

```
function getRemoteContent($resource_path)
{
    return (existsUrl($resource_path))
        ? file_get_contents($resource_path)
        : FALSE;
}
```

que se apoya en está otra (para comprobar que la URL esta disponible):

```
/**
 * Checks if a URL exists
 * From: https://cybmeta.com/comprobar-en-php-si-existe-un-archivo-o-una-url
 *
 * @param  string       $url
 * @return boolean
 */
function existsUrl($url)
{
    //Se aceptarán sólo respuestas:
    // 200 (Ok)
    // 301 (redirección permanente)
    // 302 (redirección temporal)
    $accepted_response = [ 200, 301, 302 ];

    $ch = curl_init( $url );

    //Establecer un tiempo de espera
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5 );

    //establecer NOBODY en true para hacer una solicitud tipo HEAD
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
    //Permitir seguir redireccionamientos
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    //recibir la respuesta como string, no output
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    $data = curl_exec( $ch );

    //Obtener el código de respuesta
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
    //cerrar conexión
    curl_close( $ch );


    return (in_array( $httpcode, $accepted_response ));
}
```

Lo que tienes al final es un string. Si no tienes que hacer operaciones complicadas puedes extraer los contenidos con funciones de strings, yo lo he usado para sacar ciertos elementos, metas, links...

Alternativamente hay ***librerías para trabajar con DOM***, puedes mirar: http://php.net/manual/es/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php a ver si se ajusta más a tus necesidades.

Comment: ¿Y como podria guardar los datos de esa pagina web?

Comment: @orici aparentemente el problema no es que la página no existe, sino que se llena íntegramente con llamados ajax.

Comment: @amenadiel sólo le indico cómo puede obtener el contenido de una página web

Comment: @Imanol Garmendia entiendo que tienes que acceder a un contenido, extraer, tratar y guardar parte de ese contenido y mantener actualizados los datos que guardas. Son muchas cosas, te he indicado una forma de obtener contenido, para el tratamiento como strings deberías hacer búsquedas, extraer partes, etc. Como tienes la página en concreto mira su código para ver que te interesa. Tampoco se si el método que te planteo te va a devolver todo el contenido, habría que analizar el funcionamiento del sitio, ¿has mirado si tiene una api?

Comment: gracias ante todo, si, ya he mirado si tiene o no una API y no la tiene @Orici